# Kafka custom logging handler makes django app unlisten on port

Tags: django, logging, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I have a django app and I need to send my logs to the kafka server. So I implemented a custom handler as below:

```
import logging
from kafka import KafkaProducer

class KafkaHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, hosts=['DEFAULT_KAFKA_HOST:DEFAULT_KAFKA_PORT'], topic='DEFAULT_KAFKA_TOPIC'):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        self.producer = KafkaProducer(
            bootstrap_servers=hosts,
            security_protocol='SASL_SSL',
            sasl_mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-512',
            sasl_plain_username='KAFKA_USER',
            sasl_plain_password='KAFKA_PASSWORD',
            value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'),
            linger_ms=10)
        self.topic = topic
```

The problem here is that when I run the django app via `python manage.py runserver` in my local app runs without any trouble but my localhost doesn't listen on the specific port.
output of `netstat -tulpn`:

> (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
> will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
> Active Internet connections (only servers)
> Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
> tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
> tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
> udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -
> udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           -
> udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -
> udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54922           0.0.0.0:*                           -
> udp6       0      0 :::58148                :::*                                -
> udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -

But after I comment out the producer initialization everything works as expected and django app starts to listen. `netstat -tulpn`:

> (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
> will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
> Active Internet connections (only servers)
> Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11477/python
> tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
> tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
> udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -
> udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           -
> udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -
> udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54922           0.0.0.0:*                           -
> udp6       0      0 :::58148                :::*                                -
> udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -

Comment: And you get no logs from the server at all saying its listening or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an alternative server. [Django with Gunicorn](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/) solved the problem in my similar case.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30794580)